# Creating labels from reference call

Tags: c#, label

I can't understand why my code is not functioning. I created two classes, Main and Labels, and I would like to print out label by calling Labels class inside Main. It gives me a runtime error. I Appreciate any help that you can provide.

```
  //--------------------------------------------------main class-------------------//
  namespace Test
  {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
     labels label;

     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        createLabel();
     }

     private void createLabel()
     {
        //error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
        label.printHeader();
     }
    }//form
   }//test

  // ---------------------------------- labels class-------------------------//
  namespace Test
  {
    class labels
    {
     private Label label1;

     public labels()
     {

     }

     public void printHeader()
     {
        label1 = new Label();

        label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 44);
        label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(977, 54);
        label1.Text = "MonthCalendar";
        Controls.Add(label1);
     }
   }//form
 }//test
```

Comment: You have to instantiate label first. Try adding `label = new labels();` to your Form1 constructor before calling createLabel().

Comment: Class names should be CamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instanciate

```
 private void createLabel()
     {
        label = new labels();        
 //error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
        label.printHeader();
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You declare the class, but never create an instance.

Try

```
 private void createLabel()
 {
    label = new labels();
    label.printHeader();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void createLabel()
     {
        label =new labels();//add  this
        //error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
        label.printHeader();
     }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answers.  Pasting only code is not very useful.